# Ubuntu 17.10 - Pulseaudio don't start at boot

Tags: pulseaudio

On Ubuntu 17.10, Pulseaudio don't start at boot, but when I start it manually a few times, it works !? 
I tried pulseaudio -vv : https://pastebin.com/nZRwGR7z

Comment: I tried pulseaudio -vv : (https://pastebin.com/nZRwGR7z)

Comment: You know that you can [edit] your question and add this information in? Instead of putting it in a comment, which is often not been read when people look first glance at your question.

Comment: In the same boat

Answer (score 12):

You might have to add it to systemd startup

```
systemctl --user enable pulseaudio && systemctl --user start pulseaudio
```

The flags can be configured (from the manual):

> Depending on whether --system, --user, --runtime, or --global is
>   specified, this enables the unit for the system, for the calling user
>   only, for only this boot of the system, or for all future logins of
>   all users, or only
>              this boot.

Comment: This is a defect IMO. Desktop configurations should have audio enabled by default. I end up having to have a workaround startup script check for it being disabled and re-enabling it lest it become disabled upon the next Ubuntu install from scratch. See https://askubuntu.com/a/962926/340383

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem pulseaudio daemon not starting with 
Kubuntu 17.10 on my Asus laptop.
What I found is that module **module-switch-on-connect.so** failed to load using **pulseadio -vv** command as user.

Commented out **module-switch-on-connect.so** from **/etc/pulse/default.pa** and this fixed my problem.

```
### Use hot-plugged devices like Bluetooth or USB automatically (LP: #1702794)
#.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so
#load-module module-switch-on-connect
#.endif
```

In your pastebin file I do not see an error not able to load a module by the way.